# resample function in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to convert a MATLAB script into an Octave file. I am using Octave 4.0.

In the MATLAB script, I encountered a line with the format [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html)(X, tx, fx).  Is there any equivalent function in Octave for this resample function?

I am not looking for the function [resample](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/resample.html)(X, p, q).

As per the Mathworks website:
*y = resample(x,p,q) resamples the input sequence, x, at p/q times the original sample rate.*
y = resample(x,tx,fs) uses a polyphase antialiasing filter to resample the signal at the uniform sample rate specified in fs.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need the non-uniform to uniform resampling that Matlab's `resample()` provides but Octave's `resample()` does not, you can use `interp1()` instead.

```
 y = resample(X, tx, fs)
```

can be converted as

```
 samplecount = (max(tx) - min(tx)) * fs
 y = interp1(tx, X, linspace(min(tx), max(tx), samplecount))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/resample.html) it says there is one. You should be able to use it like below like in documentation.

```
[y, h] = resample (x, p, q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please type in Octave:

```
 >>  help resample
```

Answer will be (in my computer I have installed this package before):

> error: help: the 'resample' function belongs to the signal package
>   from Octave Forge which you have installed but not loaded. To load the
>   package, run `pkg load signal' from the Octave prompt.

You must install and load **signal package**. See instructions in file  README.html in root Octave directory (example from Windows distributive):

> - Run the script build_packages.m to build and install the packages.
>     Installation is a one-time procedure. After installation packages must
>     still be loaded in order to use them with the pkg load PACKAGENAME
>     command.